# Sourcemap "sources" array links to "../../stdin" instead of actual SCSS file

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

I ran `npm update` today, and what followed is a disaster. I had trouble getting packages to install, but after everything appeared to be in the right place, I started up my `gulp` task that compiles my SCSS code into CSS.

This code reproduces my issue:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('www/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('www/css'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass'], function(){
    gulp.watch('www/sass/*.scss', {debounceDelay: 2000}, ['sass']);
});
```

After running this piece of code via `gulp default`, this is the result:

*www/sass/example.scss*

```
#test {
    color: red;
}
```

*www/css/example.css*

```
#test {
  color: red; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=example.css.map */
```

*www/css/example.css.map*

```
{"version":3,"sources":["../../stdin"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA,KAAK,CAAC;EACL,KAAK,EAAE,GAAI,GACX","file":"example.css","sourceRoot":"/sass"}
```

The `sources` array in the generated source map contains `"../../stdin/"` instead of `"example.scss"`! But why?

Comment: The issue appears to be a bug with no response from the developer yet: https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/394

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug with `node-sass` which was fixed as of `gulp-sass` version `2.1.1`. See the related issue [on Github](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/394)